# Collapse data.table based on several columns

Tags: r, data.table, bioinformatics

I have a very large `data.table` with 4 columns, only one of which is totally unique. Hard to explain but it looks like this:

```
          ENSEMBL ENTREZID SYMBOL   ALIAS
1 ENSG00000000003     7105 TSPAN6    T245
2 ENSG00000000003     7105 TSPAN6  TM4SF6
3 ENSG00000000003     7105 TSPAN6 TSPAN-6
4 ENSG00000000003     7105 TSPAN6  TSPAN6
5 ENSG00000000005    64102   TNMD  BRICD4
6 ENSG00000000005    64102   TNMD   CHM1L
```

I'm trying to collapse it based on the first 3 columns, and make the `ALIAS` column a list of the values that were collapsed.

I know I can do `results <- setDT(df)[, list(ALIAS=paste(ALIAS, collapse = '|')) , ENSEMBL]`, but then I lose the middle two cols.

Comment: If SYMBOL and ENTREZID are the same for each ENSEMBL, use that also as the grouping variable i.e. `setDT(df)[ , .(ALIAS = paste(ALIAS, collapse="|")) , c(names(df)[1:3])]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. Try

```
DT[, paste0(ALIAS, collapse="|"), by=c("ENSEMBL", "ENTREZID", "SYMBOL")]
```

With the data you have given, this gave me

```
           ENSEMBL ENTREZID SYMBOL                         V1
1: ENSG00000000003     7105 TSPAN6 T245|TM4SF6|TSPAN-6|TSPAN6
2: ENSG00000000005    64102   TNMD               BRICD4|CHM1L
```

Comment: figured this out seconds after posting

Answer (score 1):

In this case, add all the columns you want to keep to the `by` section.

```
results <- setDT(df)[, 
                     list(ALIAS=paste(ALIAS, collapse = '|')), 
                     list(ENSEMBL, ENTREZID, SYMBOL)]
```